Advanced Algebra Problem Maybe linked with Vectors?
$x^2 +y^2 + xy = 25$
$y^2 + z^2 + yz = 49$
$z^2 + x^2 + zx = 64$
Find $(x + y + z)^2 -100$
Here's My Approach :
$x^2 + y^2 -2xycos120 = 25$. This Equation looked too similar to the subtraction of the vectors Formula to me. So I Imagined x, y, z as 3 vectors in the x-y plane separated by the Angle of 120 degrees where vectors $|x' - y'| = 5$ and so on, We have to find the mod of the sum of the resultant of these vectors but I couldn't go any further as breaking them down into components pushes me back into equation 1 and I cannot think of any approach after this.
IF anyone has a solution to this problem using pure algebra or Vectors(Basic) please Assist(Preferably Vectors because I thought of it myself).

Are there any restrictions on x,y,z?

Yes It does, But I would also like to see a solution based on vectors

Taking the resultant of the polynomials, with $r=(x+y+z)^2-100$, one obtains
\begin{align*}
r&=-91,\quad x=0,y=5, z=-8,\\
r & = 29,\quad 8y=5x,5z=8x, 129x^2 = 1600.
\end{align*}

Can this solution be considered "basic"??

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad The title says "advanced" algebra problem, not "basic" algebra problem. The resultant is just a determinant, so for me this is not so advanced. But this is opinion-based, I suppose.

@DietrichBurde could you please explain how you took the resultant of the vectors?

$13x=8y+5z$ can easily be found by hand.

@memeguy The wikipedia page explains, how to take the resultant of, say, $x^2+y^2+xy-25$ and $y^2+z^2+yz-49$ with respect to $y$. This way one ends up finally with a polynomial $f(x)=0$  in one variable, which leads to the solutions. But this method is more computational than the other solutions here (so it has been downvoted).

The triangle you formed by substruction of pairs of vectors has sides $5,7,8$. By Brahmagupta's formula its area is $10\sqrt3$. On the other hand, the area of the triangle is the sum of the areas of the triangles formed by pairs of the vectors. Hence,
$$\frac12\sin(120^\circ)(xy+yz+zx)=10\sqrt3$$
and $xy+yz+zx=40$ which is enough the solve the question. The answer is $29$.

No, take $x=0$, $y=5$ and $z=-8$. Then all equations are satisfied, but $(x+y+z)^2=(-3)^2-100$ is not $29$.

I understood what he did...it should be given that all three of them are non zero otherwise triangle isn't possible

Ah, I see......

@DietrichBurde There may be other solutions. This is geometric one. $34$ was miscalculation.

@BobDobbs The triangle must be formed using the subtraction of the vectors, not the vectors themselves
